# Command pathing and 404 errors

Tags: desire2learn

I'm working on the most basic Valence use just to prove it works -- using php to run a "whoami" query.

I authenticate fine, get the userId, userKey, and userSig back. I set these in the userContext object. The call to createAuthenticatedUri seems to work well -- all parameters are in the GET url I would expect to see.

I've also verified that the command path (/d2l/api/lp/1.0/users/whoami/) is valid, from another developer who is connecting to a a completely different server.

However, when I try to make the request, D2L tells me "404 Page not found".

I can make a call to /d2l/api/versions/ and that returns just fine.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that your path `/d2l/api/lp/1.0/users/whoami/` is *not* valid: the proper route for the whoami API call is [`/d2l/api/lp/{ver}/users/whoami`](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/user.html#get--d2l-api-lp-%28D2LVERSION-version%29-users-whoami) without the trailing slash, and with the right version number filled in to target the API contract you want to target among those offered by the LMS -- in your case, that might be `/d2l/api/lp/1.0/users/whoami`, but it's also likely that you have more modern API contracts available on your LMS as well, which you can determine using the call to [retrieve the LMS' version table](http://docs.valence.desire2learn.com/res/apiprop.html#get--d2l-api-versions-).

Comment: Thanks Viktor for answering such a simple question. I had tried slash and no slash but due to an error I was introducing in my userContext, neither worked. Your answer helped me identify the real problem which was in my auth... apparently /versions/ has no security requirement.

Comment: The versions route is still only available to an application granted access to the LMS; it can just be used by the application anonymously (that is, without user tokens)... the calling app must still attach its app tokens appropriately. And no problem for the answer!